# How do I do phase shifting with javaScript?

Tags: javascript, phase

Why isn't the two phases shifting in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WH7Kf/43/

```
function phase_switch(){
    var phase;
    clicker = document.getElementById("click");
    phase=1
    switch (phase) {
        case 1:
            clicker.onclick = do_this;
            break;
        case 2:
            clicker.onclick = do_that;
            break;
    }

    function do_this (){
        alert("this");
        phase==2;
    }
    function do_that (){
        alert("that");
        phase==1;
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", phase_switch());
```

As you can probably tell Phase one is the only phase that's firing.  Why isn't phase 2 firing?

Comment: The `load` event expects a function, you need to pass a reference not the return value. Also you have some syntax issues, check your code here first http://jshint.com

Comment: how do I fix it then?

Comment: Also note that the fiddle is already setup for JavaScript `onLoad`.

Comment: You have `phase==2` when you mean `phase = 2`, etc.

Comment: the updated fiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/WH7Kf/46/

Comment: You need to call function on click and also place var of phase out of function, cause it every time become == 1. According to your style: http://jsfiddle.net/TG3Yz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it more simple:

```
var clicker = document.getElementById("click");
clicker.onclick = do_this;
function do_this (){
    alert("this");
    clicker.onclick = do_that;
}
function do_that (){
    alert("that");
    clicker.onclick = do_this;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ncz7w/

Answer (score 2):

You have a few syntax issues, from the beginning:

1) The fiddle is already setup to execute JavaScript code `onLoad`; check the sidebar for different options.

2) You're missing variable declarations. When you omit `var` the variable becomes global and it's accessible outside the function; you don't want this.

3) `=` is assignment, `==` is equality, `===` is strict equality. Look up the MDN for [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

4) I think you're over-complicating things. Try to separate concerns. Make a function that expects an element and messages, and do the logic **inside** the event handler. You can keep track of a flag to switch between two different messages, stored in an array. For example:

```
var clicker = document.getElementById("click");

/**
 * @param el DOM element
 * @param msgs Array containing 2 messages
 */
function phaseSwitch(el, msgs) {
    var flag = false;
    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert(msgs[+flag]); // casts flag to index (0|1)
        flag = !flag; // invert flag
    });
}

phaseSwitch(clicker, ['hello', 'bye']);
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/WH7Kf/48/

Answer (score 0):

Window load event occurs once in page life cycle, you are binding click handler in window load event which will gonna execute once. so `phase` will have value as 1 at the first time hence when you click on button `do_this` will execute always